# Plotting per-point alpha values in 3D scatterplot throws ValueError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in form of a 3D array, with "intensities" at every point. Depending on the intensity, I want to plot the point with a higher alpha. There are a lot of low-value outliers, so color coding (with scalar floats) won't work since they eclipse the real data.

What I have tried:

```
#this generates a 3D array with higher values around the center
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
aa = np.outer(a,a)
aaa = np.einsum("ij,jk,jl",aa,aa,aa)

x_,y_,z_,v_ = [],[],[],[]

from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb,to_rgba

for x in range(aaa.shape[0]):
    for y in range(aaa.shape[1]):
        for z in range(aaa.shape[2]):
            x_.append(x)
            y_.append(y)
            z_.append(z)
            v_.append(aaa[x,y,z])

r,g,b = to_rgb("blue")
color = np.array([[r,g,b,a] for a in v_])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = '3d')
ax.scatter(x_,y_,z_,c =color)

plt.show()
```

the scatterplot documentation says that color can be a 2D array of RGBA, which I do pass. Hoever when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 4000 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I just found my own answer.
The "A 2D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA." statement in the documentation was a bit confusing - one needs to convert the RGBA rows to RGBA objects first, so that list comprehension should read:

```
color = np.array([to_rgba([r,g,b,a]) for a in v_])
```